# Python - Pandas - read_csv - Convert a csv in a dictionary to be passed to pd.DateFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv containing some ticks of a currency pair:

```
{'bid':1.2, 'instrument': 'EUR_USD'}
{'bid':1.5, 'instrument': 'EUR_USD'}
```

I would like to convert this csv in a dictionary, e.g.:

```
mydict = {0:{'bid':1.2, 'instrument': 'EUR_USD'}, 1: {'bid':1.5, 'instrument': 'EUR_USD'}}
```

or to whatever iterable that can be read by the pandas DataFrame class:

```
pd.DataFrame(mydict)
```

which would yield to the following dataframe:

```
   bid instrument
0  1.2    EUR_USD
1  1.5    EUR_USD
```

In other words, the labels of the csv should be the columns of the dataframe.
Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

- python `3.4.1`
- pandas `0.15.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """{'bid':1.2, 'instrument': 'EUR_USD'}
{'bid':1.5, 'instrument': 'EUR_USD'}"""

# assigns pandas series of dictionary strings
s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep=';', header=None, squeeze=True)
```

***solution***

```
pd.DataFrame(s.apply(eval).tolist())
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I was wondering whether it is considered as safe to use `txt = open(_csvpath_, 'r').read()` to store the content of the csv file or I may encounter some issues with large datasets. What's your view on this?